# in deveolper console of salesforce.com error on object name while executing sql query : select pwd_c,sr_c from login_c

Tags: sql, object, salesforce

In developer console of force.com while inserting record in table I created on force.com giving  error on object name while executing SQL query:

```
select pwd_c,sr_c from login_c
```

Comment: what is the query...show something...

Answer (score 1):

Custom objects and fields will have the suffix `__c` in the API names. Note the double underscores. Your sample SOQL query only has single underscores.

See [Custom Objects](http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_custom_objects.htm?SearchType=Stem&Highlight=__c)

Incidentally, the [Salesforce StackExchange](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/57060/102) is a great place to ask Salesforce specific questions.